# How to pass entire SAML token (from ADFS) to Consumer App (travelocity)

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager, adfs2.0

I have a situation wherein, I have used the travelocity web application provided by WSO2. I have integrated ADFS with Identity Server. Travelocity has the code that can retrieve the claims that are being sent by IdP(in my case MS ADFS). However, can we get entire SAML token in the travelocity web application, so that same can be passed to desired backend via API Manager. If not how to retrieve entire SAML instead of only Claims.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LoggedInSessionBean sessionBean = (LoggedInSessionBean)session.getAttribute(SSOAgentConstants.SESSION_BEAN_NAME);
sessionBean.getSAML2SSO().getSAMLResponse();
```

will give you the saml response. 
Check the references

1.https://github.com/wso2/product-is/blob/v5.1.0/modules/samples/sso/sso-agent-sample/src/main/webapp/home.jsp#L48

2.https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/blob/master/components/agents/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/sso/agent/bean/LoggedInSessionBean.java#L242

Comment: Thanks Jenananthan. It worked. In fact that led to other problem of 'http headers too large' exception, which i posted in other place.